# Prove $\frac{|a+b|}{|a-b|} = \cot(\frac{\alpha}{2})$ where $a$ and $b$ are vectors of equal magnitudes.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors

> Prove
> $$
> \frac{|a+b|}{|a-b|} = \cot\Bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)
> $$
> where $a$ and $b$ are vectors of equal magnitudes and $\alpha$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$.

My approach:

Let
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a &= [x,y,z] \\[4pt]
b &= [p,q,r] 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Solving LHS:
\begin{align}
\frac{|a+b|}{|a-b|} 
&= \sqrt\frac{(x+p)^2+(y+q)^2+(z+r)^2}{(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2+(z-r)^2} \\
&= \sqrt\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+p^2+q^2+r^2+2(xp+yq+zr)}{x^2+y^2+z^2+p^2+q^2+r^2-2(xp+yq+zr)} \\
&= \sqrt\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+xp+yq+zr}{x^2+y^2+z^2-(xp+yq+zr)}
\end{align}

As by vector magnitude formula:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \sqrt{p^2+q^2+r^2}
$$

Now solving RHS:
$$\cot\Bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr) 
= \frac{\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)}{\cos\Bigl(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)}
$$

From here I did plenty of calculations using the vector dot product formula:
$$
\begin{gather} 
a \cdot b = |a||b| \cos(\theta) \\
\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta) - 1 = 1 - 2\sin^2(\theta)
\end{gather}
$$
I got
\begin{align} 
\cos\Bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr) 
&= \sqrt\frac{a \cdot b + |a||b|}{2|a||b|} \\
\sin\Bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr) 
&= \sqrt\frac{|a||b| - a \cdot b}{2|a||b|} 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align} 
\cot\Bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr) 
&= \sqrt\frac{a \cdot b + |a||b|}{|a||b| - a \cdot b} \\
&= \sqrt\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+p^2+q^2+r^2+xp+yq+zr}{x^2+y^2+z^2+p^2+q^2+r^2-(xp+yq+zr)} \\ 
&= \sqrt\frac{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+xp+yq+zr}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(xp+yq+zr)}
\end{align}

As you might notice LHS isn't equal to RHS. Please suggest where the error has occurred.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ ?

Comment: @Digitallis: I think it's supposed to be the angle between the two vectors, but yeah, it should be stated as part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is here: $$\cot(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\sqrt\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+p^2+q^2+r^2+xp+yq+zr}{x^2+y^2+z^2+p^2+q^2+r^2-(xp+yq+zr)}$$

You have $$|a|\ |b| = |a|^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ but you added also $p^2+q^2+r^2$.

Here's another way to solve the problem.

Since $a$ and $b$ are the same size then in the next figure we have a rhombus.

[image: Rhombus]

The diagonals (of size $|a+b|$ and $|a-b|$) are perpendicular and they bisect the angles of the rhombus. Then $\cot(\alpha/2) = \frac{|a+b|/2}{|a-b|/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since **a** and **b** are vectors of equal magnitudes, therefore **a-b** and **a+b** are the diagonal vectors of the rhombus containing **a** and **b**. By the property of rhombus, **a-b** and **a+b** are perpendicular and bisecting each other. Moreover, **a+b** bisects the angle included by the vectors **a** and **b**.  Hence $$
\frac{\frac{|a+b|}{2}}{\frac{|a-b|}{2}}=\cot \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \Rightarrow \frac{|a+b|}{|a-b|}=\cot \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)
$$